# how to use different swiperJS in one Html Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, swiper.js

I need to make two swiperjs in one html page but isn't working. I trying tow change and add new class but the result its same..

my Html

```
<!-- swiper1 Services Sections -->
 <div class="service__container container ">
            <div class="service__title">
                <h1>services</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper1 mySwiper1">
             <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="card swiper-slide1">
                <img class="img__card" src="/img/Digital.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card__info">
                  <h4 class="card__title"><b>Our service one</b></h4>
                  <p class="card__suptitle">Our service two</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card swiper-slide1">
                <img class="img__card" src="/img/coding.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card__info">
                  <h4 class="card__title"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur</b></h4>
                  <p class="card__suptitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur</p>
                </div>
</div>
<!-- swiper2 -->
<div class="customers__container container swiper mySwiper1">
           <div class="swiper-wrapper customers__img">
            <img class="swiper-slide" src="/img/customers1.png"  style="width:100%">
            <img class="swiper-slide" src="/img/custopmer2.png" style="width:100%">
            <img class="swiper-slide" src="/img/customer3.png"  style="width:100%">
        </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

and the js code for swiper1 and swiper2:

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper(".mySwiper1", {
    effect: "cube",
    grabCursor: true,
    cubeEffect: {
      shadow: true,
      slideShadows: true,
      shadowOffset: 20,
      shadowScale: 0.94,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
  });

//swiper2
 var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
    effect: "cards",
    grabCursor: true,
  });
```

the swiper2 its working as I want. but swiper1 not working.

Comment: You need to use a different class name for the "swipers". .mySwiper1 and .mySwiper2... or better yet use an id instead of a class.

Comment: can provide me simple demo please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic example

Your first slider missing the **mandatory** HTML layout (`swiper` instead of `swiper1` and `swiper-slide` instead of `swiper-slide1`).
https://swiperjs.com/get-started#add-swiper-html-layout

Wrong:

```
<div class="swiper1 will_not_work">
<!--  const swiper = new Swiper('.will_not_work', { -->
```

Correct:

```
<div class="swiper will_work">
<!--  const swiper = new Swiper('.will_work', { -->
```

#### snippet

```js
let swiper_setting = {
  spaceBetween: 100,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  }
}

let swiper_setting_two = {
  spaceBetween: 200,
}

let swiper_1 = new Swiper("[slider_one]", swiper_setting);
    
let swiper_2 = new Swiper("[slider_two]", swiper_setting_two);
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #403F6B;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 200px!important;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 40px!important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8.3.2/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8.3.2/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Slider main container --> 
<div class="swiper thumbnails-grid" slider_one>
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide"><a>Slide 1</a></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper thumbnails-grid" slider_two>
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide"><a>Slide 1</a></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

### Loop throw example (multiple sliders with same setting):

You can take the example above and loop throw all sliders (Lets say for real estate pagelist with slider for each house card **like airbnb):

```js
let swiper_setting = {
  spaceBetween: 100,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  }
}

var swiper_nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper');

/* loop throw */
  [].forEach.call(swiper_nodes, function(swiper_node) {
    // do whatever
    let swiper = new Swiper(swiper_node, swiper_setting);
  });
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #403F6B;
}

main{
 display: grid;   
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 column-gap: 3px;
}
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 200px!important;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 40px!important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8.3.2/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8.3.2/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Slider main container --> 

<main>
<div class="swiper thumbnails-grid" slider_one>
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide"><a>Slide 1</a></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<div class="swiper thumbnails-grid" slider_two>
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide"><a>Slide 1</a></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>


<div class="swiper thumbnails-grid" slider_two>
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide"><a>Slide 1</a></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the constructor of `Swiper` takes as argument one element at a time. So you should loop all the items with a `forEach` for example.

EDIT:
I made some changes in your *HTML* to fix the issues.

```js
var swiper1 = new Swiper(".mySwiper1", {
  effect: "cube",
  grabCursor: true,
  cubeEffect: {
    shadow: true,
    slideShadows: true,
    shadowOffset: 20,
    shadowScale: 0.94,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
  },
});

//swiper2
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
  effect: "cards",
  grabCursor: true,
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- swiper1 Services Sections -->
<div class="service__container container ">
  <div class="service__title">
    <h1>services</h1>
  </div>


  <div class="mySwiper1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    
      <div class="card swiper-slide">
        <img class="img__card" src="/img/Digital.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="card__info">
          <h4 class="card__title"><b>Our service one</b></h4>
          <p class="card__suptitle">Our service two</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card swiper-slide">
        <img class="img__card" src="/img/coding.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="card__info">
          <h4 class="card__title"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur</b></h4>
          <p class="card__suptitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- swiper2 -->
  <div class="customers__container container swiper mySwiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper customers__img">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="/img/customers1.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="/img/custopmer2.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="/img/customer3.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but your solutions its useful when I have two swpier with one shape. but in my case i have two different swpier shape in one html page